# Query Multiple Columns Within a Table

Tags: sql, database, oracle11g

I have a table of employees that are formatted as follows:

```
EMPLOYEE (FNAME,MINIT,LNAME,SSN(PK),BDATE,SUPERSSN(NULLABLE))
```

I need to query every employee and retrieve the following information:

FNAME(employee),LNAME(employee),SUPERSSN,(super)FNAME,(super)LNAME

UPDATED

After running this query:

```
SELECT A.FNAME,A.LNAME,A.SUPERSSN,B.FNAME,B.LNAME 
FROM EMPLOYEE 
A LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE B 
ON A.SUPERSSN = B.SSN;
```

The results were close, but when the superssn was null (CEO/Boss) it caused the remaining rows to populate as null also and did not populate with the actual supervisors ssn. I'm trying to use an IF statement to fix the problem with having a SuperSSN that is null, but I'm receiving the error: ORA-00905: missing keyword.

Below is the query that I ran that generated the error.

```
SELECT A.FNAME,A.LNAME,A.SUPERSSN,B.FNAME,B.LNAME 
FROM EMPLOYEE A LEFT IF A.SUPERSSN <> 'NULL'
JOIN EMPLOYEE B ON A.SUPERSSN = B.SSN;
```

Comment: @Tamil Selvan - I wasn't trying to indent that as code. It's sole purpose was for a simple reference to what I am trying to accomplish through a query.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select A.FName, 
       A.LNAme, 
       A.SuperSSN, 
       B.FName, 
       B.LName 
from Employee A 
Left Join Employee B
          On A.SuperSSN = B.SSN
```

Comment: @ a jay gandhi - I cleaned it up a little bit and ran it. 

`SELECT A.FNAME,A.LNAME,A.SSN,A.SUPERSSN,B.FNAME,B.LNAME 
FROM EMPLOYEE A LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE B ON A.SUPERSSN = B.SSN;`

It worked up until it hit a row that had an employee that did not have a supervisor (boss), and then it produced null results after that for all B.FNAME AND B.LNAME.

Comment: @Tamil Selvan - Would you like to help with something other than policing grammar? It would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: So, you don't want to display those employees that don't have supervisor? If that is the case, then you can replace Left Join with Inner Join.- Thanks

Comment: That is correct. I also used Inner Join and I retrieved similar results as before. The problem that I am getting is that once a employee gets processed that has no supervisor, all employees that follow show as not having a supervisor also. So they are being truncated basically. Not making any sense to me, so I'm contemplating on just creating a view and trying to query it that way.

Comment: I am wondering how inner join can bring out the same results as the left join. As far as If statement is concerned, you can try              SELECT A.FNAME,A.LNAME,A.SUPERSSN,B.FNAME,B.LNAME 
FROM EMPLOYEE A LEFT JOIN EMPLOYEE B ON A.SUPERSSN = B.SSN where A.SUPERSSN is not NULL